# For what values of $x$ is $f$ Continuous

Tags: calculus, limits

For what values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f$ continuous?

$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & \text{if}\, x \in \Bbb Q\\
       1 & \text{if}\, x \notin \Bbb Q
     \end{array}
   \right.$

The solution I found:

$f(x)$ is continuous nowhere. For, given any number $a$ and any $\delta>0$, the interval $(a-\delta, a+ \delta)$ contains infinitely many rational numbers and infinitely many irrational numbers.

Since $f(a) = 0$ or $1$, there are infinitely many numbers $x$ with $0<|x-a|< \delta $, and $|f(x) - f(a)| = 1$

Thus, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \neq f(a)$

My question: I'm having a hard time visualizing that you can't have a rational number $x$ with rational numbers on both sides of that $x$ such that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$(is that because you can go as 'deep' in to the interval as you like to reach the irrational number?). Can anybody attempt to give me some insight in to how this works?

I have never given it much thought that you can have infinitely many numbers even in the smallest of intervals, and it's pretty overwhelming for me to even imagine.

Comment: Every open set contains both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: The think to keep in mind is that between any two rational numbers, there is an irrational number, and between any two irrational numbers, there is a rational number.

Comment: this might be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286941/prove-that-between-every-rational-number-and-every-irrational-number-there-is-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0\in \mathbb Q$. Then $(x_n)$, where $x_n=x_0+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is a sequence of irrationals such that $x_n\to x_0$. But $f(x_n)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $f(x_0)=0$. Thus $(f(x_n))$ can not converge to $f(x_0)$. Thus $f$ is not continuous at any point of $\mathbb Q$.

Similarly it can be shown that $f$ is not continuous at any point of $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

when ${x \to a}$ the $f(x)$ doesn't tend to any specific number because there are infinite irrational and rational numbers near the $a$.

but $f(a)$ is either $0$ or $1$

and thus (as you noticed)  $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \neq f(a)$

so $f(x)$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequential continuity](http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_13/continuity.pdf).